# Resolve ambiguity with the [record] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

**I have a record**

As per the [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) tag [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/record/info), it's purpose is to label questions referring to the noun-use of 'Record':

> A record in programming is a data type with labels to access fields of
>   the record.

**I am recording**

However, a number of questions are using this tag where the question involves the action of recording.  Over 300 questions currently use the tags [[record] and [audio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+audio) or [[record] and [video]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+video); out of those, I haven't found one concerned with the data structure meaning.

**What to do?**

We could either:

1. Let it go.  (I can earn 2 reputations for each question I re-tag from [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) to, for example, [audio-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) or [video-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-recording).  I've done several to date, but it's getting a bit boring.)
2. Extend the meaning of the [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) tag to include the verb meaning.
3. Rename the [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) tag:

   1. There is already a synonym [records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/records), so we could just rename it to that, which implies more the noun use.
   2. Rename it to [storage-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage-record).  Credit to Wikipedia, as this is one way it distinguishes the senses for [Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record).
   3. Rename it to something else that resolves the confusion with 'recording'.
4. Remove the `Record` tag.
5. Something else I haven't thought of?

Comment: As long as your edits are reviewed, please make sure to not only correct a tag **if there is more to change**. See, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21199947. Also, do not **polish turds**. Re-writing https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21199252 did not make it any better.  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21197936 is still off-topic.

Comment: @usr2564301 Are you suggesting that tags on old, off-topic questions should not be corrected (as in, tagged correctly)?  My thinking is that if they're still on the site, they're being kept for a reason - so they should be corrected. No?