# Did anyone keep a [record]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I think we should burninate or disambiguate/split up [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record).

The tag Wiki states

> A record in programming is a data type with labels to access fields of the record.

However, it is used for

- records in a database, e.g. [together with [mysql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+mysql) or [together with [sql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+sql)
- recording audio, [especially with [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+android), also [together with [audio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+audio)
- records as a data type like the tag wiki suggests, e.g. [[record]+[delphi]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+delphi) or [[record]+[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record+java)

If we go though the Burnination criteria list:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is ambigous because it can refer to database records, audio recording or data types (and possibly other things)

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Depends on the context. Having a record of something isn't really on-topic as is but there are contexts (e.g. record types) where it is on-topic.

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

Adding information that it is about e.g. record types does add information in some cases but it can mean different things. Most programs are "keeping a record of something" after all.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, not at all

> Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?

Maybe? People might want to e.g. answer questions about record types in a programming language or recording audio. Those people might have a hard time searching for those if a generic [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) tag exists.

I propose creating a new tag [database-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-record) for database records, retagging questions about recording audio to [audio-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording), and splitting up questions about record types to language specific tags like [java-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-record) or [delphi-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-record).

As the time of writing, there are [3,558 questions tagged with [record]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record?tab=Votes).

Comment: A record in SQL is exactly what the tag wiki describes.

Comment: Something most definitely should be done. Example: seeing [mongodb] with [record] and hovering over [record] to get the, IMHO, oddly worded summary seems way "off" for a document DB. There are plenty of other examples, but seems like a massive retagging effort...

Comment: @Kit "[*MongoDB stores data records as BSON documents.*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/)" It does refer to exactly the same kind of "record".

Comment: Break this [record].

Comment: @Bergi, I suppose so, but in practice (albeit anecdotally), it seems we talk about documents. Anyway, *record* certainly seems overused like "service".

Comment: Is it time to wipe this tag from the [record]s?

Comment: "_As the time of writing, there are 3,558 questions tagged with [record]_" [\*traumatic \[tag:script\] memories resurface](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/839/575/d69.jpg)

Comment: Not keen on the [tag:java-record] or [tag:delphi-record], that might lead to many other [tag:my-favourite-programming-language-record] tags. Anyway, the language should be provided by another tag on the question. Suggest using some other language agnostic prefix (or suffix) to the new [tag:...record...] tag.

Comment: What's the [record] for the worst tag?

Comment: Change the \[record].

Comment: Related (2018): *[Resolve ambiguity with the \[record\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375349/resolve-ambiguity-with-the-record-tag)*

Answer (score 8):

I don't think the tag should be burninated. It's definitely on topic as defined by the tag wiki.

The tag also should not be split up per programming language. It refers to a general concept that can be found in SQL, in Java, in Pascal, in Haskell etc. Putting [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) together with the respective language tag is enough to classify a question. This does not cause harm, it is the [standard practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290681/1048572), and easily distinguished in a search.

I'm never against tag cleanup, of course. The [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) tag should not be used for audio, we have [audio-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) for that; also [audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiorecord) for the Android-specific API. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brecord%5D+audio) require some retagging effort.

Comment: [What is the difference between a "record" and a "row" in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31805/95176) seems to conclude that there are no records in SQL (except in PL/SQL), only the term [tag:row] should be used. The main issue I see with keeping the ambiguous [tag:record] is that people will continue using it for [tag:sql], [tag:android] and [tag:audio] questions. Even a clear indication in the tag wiki wouldn’t help since most people don’t read it.

Comment: @DidierL Ah, I come from Postgres where `record` is [a data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-pseudo.html) and can be [constructed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS), similar to a "tuple". I agree that it's not synonymous to the storage unit "row", any such usage should be cleaned up. And few SQL questions would need the tag at all, unless they are specifically about records - same for [row]s.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

- Keep the [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) for the SQL record ([sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql),... tags). Alternatively, the plain [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) related to SQL might be renamed to [sql-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-record) to disambiguate the sole [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) itself to prevent its incorrect usage.
- Introduce a new tag [record-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record-type) for the record data type used in Java and other languages. Similarly, there [were](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412162/tag-merge-maybe-option-type-and-optional-option-type) introduced [option-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option-type) not too long ago.
- Introduce a new tag [audio-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-record) for the records related to the sound records.

Comment: [sql-record] is just the [record-type] in the SQL languge. No need to distinguish them.

Comment: Note that [audio-recording] already exists.

Comment: Record should be renamed, otherwise it will be misused. (See [word])

Comment: [What is the difference between a "record" and a "row" in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31805/95176) seems to conclude that there are no records in SQL (except in PL/SQL), only the term [tag:row] should be used.